# sticky nav bar footer css is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on sticky footer. I have created html and css but css seems to be not working. can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Man\Desktop\testi.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TESTING</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/performance" id="Performance">Performance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="Library">Book Library</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
            <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
            <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
                <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center">
                    <p class="text-muted credit">Testing project <a href="www.google.com">Martin Bean</a> </p>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

testi.css

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 260px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

Comment: Does "not working" mean "not recognized"?

Comment: if I do any change in css its not reflecting. but there is no error shown. what needs to be done so that css can work for footer?

Comment: Add `<p>TEST</p>` after `<div id="footer" class="container">` and `#footer > p { color:red; }` in CSS and tell me if you see a red "TEST".

Comment: I have added but, only test is getting printed not in red.

Comment: Then I think that your problem is here: "C:\Users\Man\Desktop\testi.css". Can you use a relative path instead of that absolute path? I mean, if your .css file is near your .html file, just use "testi.css" ( otherwise, something like: ..\css\testi.css ).

Comment: I have kept my css in the same folder as html but still its not working.

Comment: actually I am running it from web.py server. do you think its any of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using firefox, You need to change file path like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Man/Desktop/testi.css">
```

Comment: yes it was browser issue. thanks but then how to change footer colors? I did #footer.navbar.navbar-inner > p { color:red; } for changing footer color but it didnt worked.

Comment: use like this : #footer .navbar .navbar-inner  p { color:red; }

Comment: thanks gaurav for help but it works when I open the html file. when I am using it with web.py, I cannot see the change in color. do you know how can I change that colors in html when using web.py?